# Replacing, updating, and saving text file for ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to update my `ListView` text file by replacing the word I just edited from returning from a Second Activity. Currently the output I am getting is a `Toast` of the word I just edited in the variable `name` in my `onActivityResult()`.

How my app works.

1. Tap on item in ListView
2. Opens to Activity 2 with tapped item in EditText
3. edit the item and press save to return to first activity
4. edited item returns in variable `name` and is displayed in popup (toast)

I want to replace the item I just edited with the old item and save it so then when I reopen the app, the updated/edited item is in place of the old item.

I feel as though I have the parts to complete this but I am just starting on android development so I taking quite a while to figure this out. I was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> todoItems;        
    private ArrayAdapter<String> todoAdapter;       // declare array adapter which will translate the piece of data to teh view
    private ListView lvItems;                   // attach to list view
    private EditText etNewItem;
    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 20;
    //private Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
        etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);        // now we have access to ListView
        //populateArrayItems();                 // call function
        readItems();        // read items from file
        todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);   //create adapter
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);        // populate listview using the adapter 
        //todoAdapter.add("item 4");
        setupListViewListener();
        setupEditItemListener();
        //onActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE, RESULT_OK, );
    }

    private void launchEditItem(String item) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("itemOnList", item);     // list item into edit text
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
        //startActivity(i);
    }

    private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
        lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                String text = (String) lvItems.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                launchEditItem(text);
            }

        });
    }

    private void setupListViewListener() {
        lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                todoItems.remove(pos);
                todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // has adapter look back at the array list and refresh it's data and repopulate the view
                writeItems();   
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onAddedItem(View v) {
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
        todoAdapter.add(itemText);  // add to adapter
        etNewItem.setText("");      //clear edit text
        writeItems();       //each time to add item, you want to write to file to memorize
    }

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));   //populate with read
        }catch (IOException e) {    // if files doesn't exist  
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, todoItems);  // pass todoItems to todoFile
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            String name = data.getExtras().getString("EditedItem");
            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //writeItems();
        }
    }
}
```

If needed, I'll post my second Activity as well but I don't think it is necessary. However ask and you shall receive!

Comment: Could you describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki sorry if I was unclear. I'll edit the question

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki done have a look!

Comment: Ok, now I get what you mean. :-) Tell me if I'm correct - in this `onActivityResult()` method, you're getting proper value to name variable, but you need to save it for further use, right?

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki yes that is correct!

Answer (score 3):

The solution you came up with is a bit basic and really limits you if it goes about resolving problem you mentioned. What I mean is that the `Adapter` you're using for your `ListView` consists only of simple `ArrayList<String>`, which prevents you from knowing which element is `name` you're looking for.

Better solution would be to create your own `Adapter` where each element would have a special key or something, but I'm afraid it's a bit too complicated for you for now. Keep in mind that it's possible and often very useful to create custom `Adapter`s though.

What I thought could be possible in your case is a little hack maybe, but it works ONLY if you're totally sure that `name` is always stored at n-th position, let's say at 10th position.

Then you can do this:

```
private final int NAME_POSITION = 10;
```

Now that you have this position, you should find 10th line in your file, erase it and store new value. I won't be writing this code, because it's not really related to this question. There is a lot of questions about file reading/writing in Java on Stackoverflow that you should easily find the solution if you don't know how to do it yet. Basically you have to put this in this place:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            String name = data.getExtras().getString("EditedItem");
            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Write your name to file now
        }
    }
```

The second approach would be to forget about files and use `SharedPreferences` for the updated name:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        String name = data.getExtras().getString("EditedItem");
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPrefrences sp = getSharedPreferences("MySavedValues", 0); // Open SharedPreferences with name MySavedValues
        Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("Name", name); // Store name with key "Name". This key will be then used to retrieve data.         
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

and in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
    etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);        // now we have access to ListView
    //populateArrayItems();                 // call function
    readItems();        // read items from file

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MySavedValues", 0);   // Open SharedPreferences with name MySavedValues
    String name = sp.getString("Name", ""); // If there isn't any string stored with key "Name", it will return empty string
    if(!name.isEmpty()) {
        todoItems.set(NAME_POSITION, name);
    }

    todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);   //create adapter
    lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);        // populate listview using the adapter 
    //todoAdapter.add("item 4");
    setupListViewListener();
    setupEditItemListener();
    //onActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE, RESULT_OK, );
}
```

I haven't tested it, so you have to do it yourself. Also if you find my answer a bit complicated, feel free to ask about anything.

Comment: Thank you for your effort I'm going to read/test this to see if it works!

Comment: I'm not sure about the absolute position of `name` when it is returned in ``. However, in my `setupEditItemListener()` when I tap the item, I believe `onItemClick()` retrieves the position of the tapped item but I think it is only being used in the 2nd activity and the `pos` data is not returned back to the 1st Activity

Comment: I am getting an error at `todoItems.get(NAME_POSITION) = name;` because the variable has to be on the left side. Not sure if you wanted name to be on the left. Also at `String name = settings.getString("Name", "");` I am getting a red line under `settings` not sure what you wanted to do this with.

Comment: @Liondancer Sorry, wrong copy/paste with those `settings`. :-) I updated those two things. Check it out now.

Comment: This code didn't do what I wanted to do but I think it is because there is no implementation of the position of the tapped item. In my `steupEditItemListener()` there is a `int pos` in `onItemClick()`. I feel as though when I tap on the `ListView` this information is passed to `pos` as the position of the tapped item. I think `pos` has to be used in the code you gave me but I'm not sure how. Perhaps `NAME_POSITION = pos` but that would not be legal. I'm a bit new to Java and Android dev so this is all pretty complicated for me.

Comment: Check if it works after closing the application and launching it again.

Are you familiar with debugging tool in Eclipse? Have you used it? If not, please read about it, because it would help you a lot.

Comment: I am not familiar with it =/ not sure where I can learn it efficiently

Comment: There's a lot stuff you're missing and I'm not sure if I can give you the knowledge you need in here, but tomorrow I'll try to update my answer and give you a few more hints which SHOULD work. Then I'll have more time to explain it.

Comment: Hey! I figured it out! if you want to know what I did I can show you if you want!

Comment: @Liondancer I'm glad you worked it out. Yes, you may show how you solved your problem because it could help others.